# Android in-app billing handling google Server Response Codes

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-billing

According to google Implementing In-app Billing documentation , that's google will sends the response code synchronously as an integer mapped to the RESPONSE_CODE key in the response Bundle
[In-app Billing Reference](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#billing-codes)

now that i have this code in my app

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1001) {
  int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
  String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
  String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     try {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
        String sku = jo.getString("productId");
        alert("You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice,
           adventurer!");
      }
      catch (JSONException e) {
         alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
}
```

how i can handling google response codes , for example

```
if (responsecode == 7) do somthing
```

i tryed to make this

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK || resposeCode == 7) do somthing
```

and

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK || resultCode == 7) do somthing
```

but of course i'm here because nothing works for me

update :

```
 public class Test extends Activity {

IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                   IBinder service) {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
};

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    Intent serviceIntent =
            new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b1.setTypeface(font);
    b2.setTypeface(font);
 b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         buy(id);

  }}

   @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mService != null) {
        unbindService(mServiceConn);
    }
}

   public void buy(String id) {
       try {
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), selected, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

        this.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
        String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "request true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "result true ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (responseCode == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), " response = 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if(responseCode == 7){
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "response = 7 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }




        }
    }
}
}
```

logfile : it's give purchaser successful and downloaded item but next time i try buy same thing before buyintent start , it's crash and give this error
this code what give error next time

```
    this.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));

    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.app.inapp.bill.Test.buy(Test.java:258)
at com.app.inapp.bill.Test$3.onClick(Test.java:226)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4651)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19310)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what exactly you want ?

Comment: if item already owned i want  to downloaded for user without buy it again , because he already have it

Comment: I have updated my answer try it and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok thx  Sree Reddy Menon i find my solution :

look like google don't allow to start buyintent when you already have item and give nullpointerexption , so i used  getPurchases() to find if user have the item or no , and call buy intent only if user don't have the item

example for anyone have same problem ,this my buy method right now

```
   public void donate(String selected) {
   try {
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), selected, "inapp", "bGoa+Vlc/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

        if(pendingIntent != null) {
            this.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
        }else{
            try{
            Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
            int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
            if (response == 0) {
                ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
                        ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
                ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
                        ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
                ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
                        ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
                String continuationToken =
                        ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

                for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
                    String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
                    String signature = signatureList.get(i);
                    String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

                    if (sku.equals(selected)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "user have this item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        break;
                    }


                }


                // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again
                // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
            }}catch (RemoteException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: But Never Call .getPurchases from MainThread. Please use IABHelper Classes. and Watch this video @21.20  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgcJPIRpfSk

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Billing response codes
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK = 0;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED = 1;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE = 3;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE = 4;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR = 6;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED = 7;
    public static final int BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_NOT_OWNED = 8;
```

Handling the response

```
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1001) {
          int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
          String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
          String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

         if (responseCode == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
             try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                alert("You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice,
                   adventurer!");
              }
              catch (JSONException e) {
                 alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
          } else if (responseCode == BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
     alert("You have already bought the item");

        }  else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
     alert("Purchase canceled ");
}
else{
     alert("Unknown error");

}
}

        }
```

add as your response codes on if else.

Comment: please log the error and response code. "not working " will not give solution. just log the response and ResponseCode  and debug onActivityResult.!

Comment: Just let me know if you are calling startActivityforResult from Fragment. You should add super .

Comment: it's same error where google response with your already have the item , as if  onActivityResult didn't called at all , but when i try to buy something new , it's work and download my item by using   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)

Comment: hmm i called onActivityResult normal wirhout super or anything , just like google documentation

Comment: Dude, ACTIVITY.RESLUT_OK  doesnt mean that the purchase was successful. and you should validate the responseCode of Purchased item Response.. not resultCode .!  please log the responseCode and check.            int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE",-1);

Comment: sorry for long wait , i try to test different things , look like i have serious problem not with handling google response  but also with handling ActivityResult , update my question with my code and logfile hope this help you  <it's give purchaser successful but no response on activityResult>